# Hive is always running in local mode

Tags: hadoop, hive, cluster-computing, local, mode

I have hadoop cluster (3 nodes) all nodes are running ok. but Hive is always runs queries in local mode. I sat the mapred.job.tracker to the tracker host and still not working.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the issue is in some hadoop configuration. It seems that Hive was not able to detect the cluster configuration.

Since I'm using hadoop 2.6.0, I've changed mapred-site.xml according to the release, see below my mapred-site.xml file

```html
   <property>
        <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
        <value>yarn</value>
    </property>
<property>
  <name>mapreduce.jobtracker.address</name>
  <value>hadoopMaster:54311</value>
  <description>The host and port that the MapReduce job tracker runs
  at.  If "local", then jobs are run in-process as a single map
  and reduce task.
  </description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>mapreduce.jobtracker.http.address</name>
  <value>hadoopMaster:50030</value>
  <description>The host and port that the MapReduce job tracker runs
  at.  If "local", then jobs are run in-process as a single map
  and reduce task.
  </description>
</property>
```

And this is the default values for mapred-site.xml from Apache Hadoop.

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.0/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/mapred-default.xml